# QSettings Обработка данных и работа с реестром

Tags: c++, qt, qsettings

Всем привет. У меня есть текстовый редактор. При закрытии программы сохряняю имя и путь к файлу в реестр, что бы при открытии его открыть.
Открытие:

```
QSettings settings(QCoreApplication::organizationName(), QCoreApplication::applicationName());
settings.setValue("hyperText/fileName", fileName);
settings.setValue("hyperText/fileUrl", fileUrl);
settings.sync();
```

Считывание:

```
QSettings settings(QCoreApplication::organizationName(), QCoreApplication::applicationName());
return settings.value("hyperText/fileUrl" + "hyperText/fileName");
```

Но как сохранять и открывать путь и название файла, если их несколько (не зная предварительно их количество)?

Comment: Сохраняйте `QStringList` со списком файлов, он поддерживается в `QSettings` из коробки без необходимости костылей

Answer (score 3, accepted):

К этому можно подойти по разному, к примеру, в `QSettings` есть пара [`beginWriteArray`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html#beginWriteArray)/[`endArray`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html#endArray). Там же, в документации, есть и пример использования. Это предпочтительный метод.

Либо же можно воспользоваться тем, что `QList` может быть сериализован в `QDataStream` посредством `operator<<` и записывать одно значение в реестр, предварительно превращая список в одну строку.